# heroku node.js bash: node: command not found

Tags: node.js, heroku, web-deployment

there seems to be a strange problem with the deployment of my app on heroku on cedar stack where my node process doesn't even get called

my Procfile is as follows:

```
web: node web.js
```

and my package.json file:

```
{
 "name": "fuuzik",
 "version": "0.0.1",
 "dependencies": {
   "express": "3.x",
   "jade":"*",
   "mime-magic":"*"
  },
 "engines": {
  "node": "0.8.x",
  "npm": "1.1.x"
  }
}
```

So after i commit and push heroku detects it's a node app fine and builds my dependancies correctly and even says that it deployed ..  yet the app is crashed immediately on deploy and heroku logs returns:

```
2012-08-29T08:52:14+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy d9fdb17 by he610@doc.ic.ac.uk
2012-08-29T08:52:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting 
2012-08-29T08:52:14+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-08-29T08:52:16+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node web.js`
2012-08-29T08:52:16+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found
2012-08-29T08:52:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127 
2012-08-29T08:52:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

foreman runs fine and there are a couple of .php files around the root directory (since I am porting some old code) but I am pretty sure that should be allowed by the logic of Procfiles

As requested here's the output of npm install locally:

```
--[/DEBUG]--
jade@0.27.2 node_modules/jade
├── commander@0.6.1
└── mkdirp@0.3.0

express@3.0.0rc3 node_modules/express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── cookie@0.0.4
├── crc@0.2.0
├── commander@0.6.1
├── debug@0.7.0
├── mkdirp@0.3.3
├── send@0.0.3 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.4.3 (pause@0.0.1, bytes@0.1.0, qs@0.4.2, formidable@1.0.11)

mime-magic@0.3.0 node_modules/mime-magic
```

and here's the git log when i push (it's a bit big so i linked it):

http://pastebin.com/d424TBfR

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you specify a complete version for node / npm (without the .x)?

Comment: just tried with node 0.8.7 and npm 1.1.4 .. i also tried removing my local node_modules folder (although that shouldn't be related or anything) no luck .. :(

Comment: What happens when you run `npm install` locally?  Also, provide the earlier output of when you push it to Heroku.

Comment: I edited the question to include that

Comment: Well, your pastebin clearly shows a bunch of errors.  I'm surprised you're surprised to find it's not working :-)  In particular, you're using a library mime-magic that appears to be a wrapper around some native code that isn't available on Heroku.

Comment: where do you see the errors? it says it builds the dependencies fine .. besides i did suspect that was the problem and tried pushing removing that dependency and code that uses it .. it was exactly the same problem ..

Answer (score 4):

Try deleting your Procfile.

Apparently, the Procfile indicates heroku to run the app using `node main.js` but node is not  a valid command since it is not included in the PATH varialbe, or similar.

By deleting the Procfile, heroku detects that the app is a meteor app and runs it using node's binary with the full path.

Also, remember the `ROOT_URL` must be set beginning with http://

Answer (score 3):

These commands solved the issue

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
git commit -am "empty" --allow-empty
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

Libmagic (required by mime-magic) is expecting a different version of libc then heroku provides. You will need to find an alternative library or compile it your self for heroku's version of libc.