# Heroku - bash: node: command not found. Process error code 127

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment

I am struggling with the problem that I am not able to deploy my node application to the Heroku. Previously I have done it several times and everything was working like a charm. Now I encounter `bash: node: command not found`. I have no idea what to do to get rid of this problem.

My `Procfile`:

```
web: node ./src/index.js
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "scheduler_be",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --forceExit",
    "start": "nodemon ./src/index.js --development"

  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/jablonskipj/scheduler-be.git"
  },
  "author": "Patryk Jablonski",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/jablonskipj/scheduler-be/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/jablonskipj/scheduler-be#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "knex": "^0.16.5",
    "node": "^12.2.0",
    "node-cron": "^2.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.9",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "pg": "^7.8.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "smsapi": "^1.5.7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.2.0"
  }
}
```

and my `index.js`:

```
const express = require('express')
const reminderRoutes = require('./routes/Routes')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8006

console.log(PORT)

const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/reminder', reminderRoutes)


app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

I have tried to log out anything valuable by using `heroku logs -t` but this does not give me anything more than Process error code 127.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

I have tried things suggested in the [heroku node.js bash: node: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174330/heroku-node-js-bash-node-command-not-found) but nothing helped. That question was asked 7 years ago and never answered, so I am pretty sure that my problem is different here.

Is there anyone from the Heroku team that could help me with the problem? Recently I have tried to force the use of the `npm` in version `6.5.0` and this has no effect. I have read the whole https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys and applied all of the suggestions. How can I force Heroku to give me more info about what is exactly the problem?

EDIT:

I have also tried without the `Procfile` and app still does not work. Now I receive `bash: npm: command not found` so I am getting pretty frustrated, because of that I have another Nodejs app deployed on the Heroku and it is deploying without a problem.

EDIT:

I have checked for multiple times and the buildset is `heroku/nodejs`. Is there anything else that I can do to deploy this app to the heroku somehow?

Additionally here is a screen of the logs that I can see in the Heroku console

[image]

The log file - text version:

```
2019-05-21T06:59:52.401049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-05-21T06:59:53.969667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-21T06:59:53.952550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-05-21T06:59:53.901105+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found
2019-05-21T08:01:13.046896+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `node src/schedule.js` by user scheduler@addons.heroku.com
2019-05-21T08:01:18.939306+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8582]: Starting process with command `node src/schedule.js`
2019-05-21T08:01:19.672108+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8582]: State changed from starting to up
2019-05-21T08:01:20.475107+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8582]: State changed from up to complete
2019-05-21T08:01:20.454340+00:00 heroku[scheduler.8582]: Process exited with status 127
2019-05-21T08:01:20.379550+00:00 app[scheduler.8582]: bash: node: command not found
2019-05-21T08:21:17.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user manilandiasalon@gmail.com
2019-05-21T08:22:22.166110+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-21T08:22:27.607552+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-05-21T08:22:29.106294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-21T08:22:29.182031+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-05-21T08:22:29.086883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-05-21T08:22:28.981729+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found
2019-05-21T08:22:20.927103+00:00 app[api]: Deploy d783e9a4 by user manilandiasalon@gmail.com
2019-05-21T08:22:20.927103+00:00 app[api]: Release v30 created by user manilandiasalon@gmail.com
2019-05-21T08:22:36.960377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node index.js`
2019-05-21T08:22:39.080765+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-05-21T08:22:39.061234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2019-05-21T08:22:38.981195+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: node: command not found
2019-05-21T08:22:27.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
```

After raising a ticket in the Heroku support page I received info that my application acts like a containerized app. In this case, I am not able to do anything about that and I have to wait till support team fix my issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [heroku node.js bash: node: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12174330/heroku-node-js-bash-node-command-not-found)

Comment: @Garret the end result seems to be the same but topic that you have linked is almost 7 years old and I am pretty sure that it has nothing to my problem. Additionally, I have tried all of the suggestions from it and nothing works. Is there a change that you could help me with the problem?

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Could you add the entire logs as text file instead of image and remove any secrets from it?

Comment: @PrivateOmega done :)

Answer (score 1):

I cannot be sure as to what the problem might be that you are facing specifically but I can maybe provide you with some pointers.

Also I am hoping you have already checked out the generic solutions like checking if the official build pack is set or setting node engine's specified in **package.json** etc.

If all these doesn't work, could you try a `heroku restart`.

Comment: When projects contain both `package-lock` and `yarn.lock` Heroku gives another error. When it comes to the troubleshooting and resart I have also done it and I did not work.

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Yes, sorry will remove it. Could you try to bash into the instance and see if node or npm command works, maybe it requires exact path which might be a pointer to help us solve tihs.

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński how about this? And also please run `heroku buildpacks` to see the buildpacks used in it.

Comment: I have run the `heroku buildpacks` and the result is: `=== reminders-be Buildpack URL
heroku/nodejs
`

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Try removing the proc file because it enforces to run `web: node ./src/index.js` meaning it tries to run index.js with node even though it is not available,  so if you remove the proc file maybe Heroku might autodetect the application and run it using node binary's full path. Also don't forget to set main parameter in package.json root to point to your index.js file.

Comment: I already did it. For node environment, heroku executer npm start and the end result is `bash: npm: command not found` :D. The worst thing is that I cannot create a ticket in Heroku, because when I open the create ticket page and select the application that is causing problem I get the view without any send/confirm button :/. Everything is against me :D.

Comment: This is one of the most baffling problems I've ever encountered. Maybe the issue has something to do at their end. Did you try deleting the instance and launching a new one with same proc file and buildpack settings. Just want to know the end result of it out of curiousity.

Comment: I have finally created the ticket in Heroku support system and a guy told me that the problem is that my heroku app acts like a containerized app. We are working together to fix the problem. The funny thing is that in the meantime I have created second heroku app and I have the same problem there :/

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with heroku, but I can say that whenever you have a "bash: BLANK not found" error it usually means you are using the command from somewhere that does not know about the command.

So, in this case, node is not installed in a location that the current working directory knows about. Maybe you are telling heroku an incorrect location to look for node or something, or node is just not properly installed. Check where node is installed and if you need to tell heroku where it is installed then make sure the search paths are correct?

Comment: Well the thing is Heroku is a cloud platform provider and it by itself contains run time environments in those instances which are configured by itself, so an user doesn't need to specify where the node is installed or anything that we do in our desktop environment.